# Printing Python Variable to PHP page

Tags: php, python

I am trying to print a python variable to a php page. I have my php script status.php shown below

```
<?php
$result = json_decode(exec('python status.py'), true);
echo $result;
?>
```

This php page calls the status.py python page which is listed below

```
import json
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setuip(23, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
input_state = GPIO.input(23)
if input_state == False:
  print("Door is closed")
  D = 1
elif input_state == True:
  print("Door is open")
  D = 0

print json.dumps(D)
```

I can get the shell command to print the php variable which when the door is closed comes out to be 
Door is closed
1
However I can't get the variable 1 to print to the php page when I run it from the browser. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

By changing 
`$result = json_decode(exec('python status.py'), true);`
to 
`$result = json_decode(exec('sudo python status.py'), true);` it enabled the variable to be passed from the python script to the php script. It seems there was an access problem when accessing the file via webrowser.